# Python matrix implementation

Tags: python, performance, matrix

I created a simple matrix implementation and would like some critique of it, for example:

- Things I could add to make it more useful
- Ways I could make it more efficient (for example __pow__ or ref())
- How I could improve my code format / comments

Source:

```
import math


class InvalidMatrixDimensions(Exception):
    """Matrix was created with invalid matrix compared to its raw list"""
    pass


class MismatchedMatrixDimensions(Exception):
    """Arithmetic was attempted on one or more matrix with invalid or incompatible dimensions"""
    pass


class UninvertibleMatrix(Exception):
    """Matrix is uninvertible (cannot be inverted)"""
    pass


class CombinedMatrix:
    """Class for performing gaussian elimination operations"""

    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        if not (left.width == right.width and left.height == right.height and left.width == left.height):
            raise MismatchedMatrixDimensions

    def add(self, row_origin, row_dest, coef):
        """Add one row to another, multiplied by a coefficient

        Arguments:
        row_origin -- the y value of the row you're adding (integer)
        row_dest -- the y value of the row you're adding to (integer)
        coef -- the coefficient you're multiplying row_origin by (float)"""
        for y in range(self.left.width):
            self.left[y, row_dest] = self.left[y, row_dest] + (self.left[y, row_origin] * coef)
            self.right[y, row_dest] = self.right[y, row_dest] + (self.right[y, row_origin] * coef)

    def mult(self, row, coef):
        """Multiply the row by a coefficient

        Arguments:
        row -- the y value of the row you're multiplying (integer)
        coef -- the coefficient you're multiplying the row by (float) """
        for y in range(self.left.width):
            self.left[y, row] = self.left[y, row] * coef
            self.right[y, row] = self.right[y, row] * coef

    def swap(self, row1, row2):
        """Swap two rows

        Arguments:
        row1 -- the y value of the first row you want to swap
        row2 -- the y value of the second row you want to swap"""
        for y in range(self.left.width):
            temp = self.left[y, row2]
            self.left[y, row2] = self.left[y, row1]
            self.left[y, row1] = temp

            temp = self.right[y, row2]
            self.right[y, row2] = self.right[y, row1]
            self.right[y, row1] = temp

    def sort_pivot(self, row):
        """Move down the matrix, looking for the first pivot found in the correct column
        if none found matrix is uninvertible (as there must be a zero column)

        Arguments:
        row -- the y value of the row you want to find the pivot for (pivot must be at (row, row))"""
        i = row
        while i < self.left.height and self.left.get_pivot(i) != row:
            i += 1
        if i == self.left.height:
            raise UninvertibleMatrix
        else:
            self.swap(i, row)


class Matrix:
    """Matrix class allows for indexing"""

    @staticmethod
    def identity(size):
        """Get an identity matrix with dimensions (size x size)

        Arguments:
        size -- the dimension of the square matrix (integer)"""
        matrix = Matrix(size, size)
        for i in range(size):
            matrix[i, i] = 1
        return matrix

    def __init__(self, width, height=None, oheight=None):
        """Create a matrix,

        Can be called in the following ways:
        Matrix(raw_2d_list)                - calculates the width and height of the matrix
        Matrix(raw_2d_list, width, height) - if width and height are known, the speeds up the initialization.
        Matrix(width, height)              - creates a zero matrix of the given dimensions

        Arguments:
        raw_2d_list -- a two dimensional array
        width -- integer describing the amount of columns in the matrix
        height -- integer describing the amount of rows in the matrix"""
        if type(width) is int:
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            if self.width > 0 and self.height > 0:
                self._raw = [[0] * height for x in range(width)]
            else:
                raise InvalidMatrixDimensions
        else:
            self._raw = width
            if oheight is not None:
                self.width = height
                self.height = oheight
            else:
                self.width = len(self._raw)
                if self.width > 0:
                    self.height = len(self._raw[0])
                    if self.height > 0:
                        for row in self._raw:
                            if len(row) != self.height:
                                raise InvalidMatrixDimensions
                    else:
                        raise InvalidMatrixDimensions
                else:
                    raise InvalidMatrixDimensions

    def get_pivot(self, row):
        """Find the pivot for that row

        Arguments:
        row -- the row you want to find the pivot for"""
        y = 0
        while y < self.height and self[y, row] == 0:
            y += 1
        if y == self.height:
            return None
        else:
            return y

    def ref(self):
        """Converts the matrix to row echelon form"""
        if self.width == self.height:
            if self.width == 1:
                return self.copy()
            else:
                template = Matrix.identity(self.width)
                comb = CombinedMatrix(self.copy(), template)
                for i in range(comb.left.height):
                    comb.sort_pivot(i)
                    for j in range(i+1, comb.left.height):
                        comb.add(i, j, -comb.left[i, j]/comb.left[i, i])
                return comb.left
        else:
            raise UninvertibleMatrix

    def det(self):
        """Finds the determinant of the matrix"""
        ref = self.ref()
        total = 1
        for i in range(self.width):
            total *= ref[i, i]
        return total

    def inverse(self):
        """Find the inverse of a matrix"""
        if self.width == self.height:
            if self.width == 1:
                return Matrix([[1/self[0, 0]]], 1, 1)
            else:
                template = Matrix.identity(self.width)
                comb = CombinedMatrix(self.copy(), template)
                for i in range(comb.left.height):
                    comb.sort_pivot(i)
                    comb.mult(i, 1.0/comb.left[i, i])
                    for j in range(comb.left.height):
                        if i != j:
                            comb.add(i, j, -comb.left[i, j])
                return comb.right
        else:
            raise UninvertibleMatrix

    def copy(self):
        """Return an exact copy of the matrix (none-deep, individual values will NOT be copied)"""
        return Matrix([[v for v in row] for row in self._raw], self.width, self.height)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            if self.width != other.width or self.height != other.height:
                raise MismatchedMatrixDimensions
            return Matrix([[other[x, y] + self[x, y] for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width, self.height)
        else:
            return Matrix([[self[x, y] + other for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width, self.height)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            if self.width != other.width or self.height != other.height:
                raise MismatchedMatrixDimensions
            return Matrix([[self[x, y] - other[x, y] for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)],
                          self.width, self.height)
        else:
            return Matrix([[self[x, y] - other for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width,
                          self.height)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            if self.width != other.height:
                raise MismatchedMatrixDimensions
            return Matrix([[ sum(self[i, y] * other[x, i] for i in range(self.width)) for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(other.width)], other.width, self.height)
        else:
            return Matrix([[self[x, y] * other for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width,
                          self.height)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            return self * other.inverse()
        else:
            return Matrix([[self[x, y] / other for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width,
                          self.height)

    def __invert__(self):
        return self.inverse()

    def __abs__(self):
        return Matrix([[abs(self[x, y]) for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width,
                      self.height)

    def __mod__(self, other):
        return Matrix([[self[x, y] % other for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width,
                      self.height)

    def __neg__(self):
        return Matrix([[-self[x, y] for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width,
                      self.height)

    def __int__(self):
        return Matrix([[int(self[x, y]) for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width,
                      self.height)

    def __float__(self):
        return Matrix([[float(self[x, y]) for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width,
                      self.height)

    def __pow__(self, power, modulo=None):
        """Raise a matrix to a power,
        matrix must be square and power must be an integer"""
        if type(power) is int:
            if power < 1:
                matrix = self.inverse()
                power *= -1
            else:
                matrix = self.copy()
            cpow = 1
            powers = [None] * (power+1)
            powers[1] = matrix
            while cpow < power:
                remaining = power - cpow
                if remaining >= cpow:
                    matrix = matrix * matrix
                    cpow *= 2
                    powers[cpow] = matrix
                elif powers[remaining] is not None:
                    matrix = matrix * powers[remaining]
                    cpow += remaining
                elif remaining % 2 == 1:
                    matrix = matrix * powers[1]
                    cpow += 1
                    powers[cpow] = matrix
                else:
                    nextpow = math.floor(remaining/4) * 4
                    if powers[nextpow] is not None:
                        matrix = matrix * powers[nextpow]
                        cpow += nextpow
                        powers[cpow] = matrix
                    else:
                        matrix = matrix * powers[2]
                        cpow += 2
                        powers[cpow] = matrix
            del powers
            return matrix
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __call__(self, *filters):
        """Apply some filters to every element in the matrix

        Arguments:
        *filters - any amount of callables with arguments x, y, v (v is the element)"""
        def applyAll(x, y, v):
            for filter in filters:
                v = filter(x, y, v)
            return v
        return Matrix([[applyAll(x, y, self[x, y]) for x in range(self.height)] for y in range(self.width)], self.width,
                      self.height)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            if self.width == other.width and self.height == other.height:
                for x in range(self.width):
                    for y in range(self.height):
                        if self[x, y] != other[x, y]:
                            return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            for x in range(self.width):
                for y in range(self.height):
                    if self[x, y] != other:
                        return False
        return True

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            if self.width == other.width and self.height == other.height:
                for x in range(self.width):
                    for y in range(self.height):
                        if self[x, y] == other[x, y]:
                            return True
            else:
                return True
        else:
            for x in range(self.width):
                for y in range(self.height):
                    if self[x, y] == other:
                        return True
        return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            if self.width == other.width and self.height == other.height:
                for x in range(self.width):
                    for y in range(self.height):
                        if self[x, y] <= other[x, y]:
                            return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            for x in range(self.width):
                for y in range(self.height):
                    if self[x, y] <= other:
                        return False
        return True

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            if self.width == other.width and self.height == other.height:
                for x in range(self.width):
                    for y in range(self.height):
                        if self[x, y] < other[x, y]:
                            return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            for x in range(self.width):
                for y in range(self.height):
                    if self[x, y] < other:
                        return False
        return True

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            if self.width == other.width and self.height == other.height:
                for x in range(self.width):
                    for y in range(self.height):
                        if self[x, y] >= other[x, y]:
                            return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            for x in range(self.width):
                for y in range(self.height):
                    if self[x, y] >= other:
                        return False
        return True

    def __le__(self, other):
        if type(other) is Matrix:
            if self.width == other.width and self.height == other.height:
                for x in range(self.width):
                    for y in range(self.height):
                        if self[x, y] > other[x, y]:
                            return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            for x in range(self.width):
                for y in range(self.height):
                    if self[x, y] > other:
                        return False
        return True

    def __contains__(self, item):
        for x in range(self.width):
            for y in range(self.height):
                if self[x, y] == item:
                    return True
        return False

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        x, y = item
        if type(x) is slice or type(y) is slice:
            subset = self._raw[y]
            if type(subset[0]) is not list:
                subset = [subset]
            yisslice = type(x) is slice
            for cx in range(len(subset)):
                subset[cx] = subset[cx][x]
                if not yisslice:
                    subset[cx] = [subset[cx]]
            return Matrix(subset)
        else:
            return self._raw[y][x]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        x, y = item
        if type(x) is slice or type(y) is slice:
            start_x, end_x = x, x
            if type(x) is slice:
                start_x = x.start
                if start_x is None:
                    start_x = 0
                end_x = x.stop
                if end_x is None:
                    end_x = self.width
            else:
                end_x += 1
            start_y, end_y = y, y
            if type(y) is slice:
                start_y = y.start
                if start_y is None:
                    start_y = 0
                end_y = y.stop
                if end_y is None:
                    end_y = self.height
            else:
                end_y += 1
            if type(value) is Matrix:
                if end_x - start_x == value.width and end_y - start_y == value.height:
                    for x in range(start_x, end_x):
                        for y in range(start_y, end_y):
                            self._raw[y][x] = value._raw[y-start_y][x-start_x]
                else:
                    raise MismatchedMatrixDimensions
            else:
                for x in range(start_x, end_x):
                    for y in range(start_y, end_y):
                        self[x, y] = value
        else:
            self._raw[y][x] = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str("(" + ")\n(".join(" ".join(str(i) for i in row) for row in self._raw) + ")")
```

Examples:

```
test = Matrix([
    [2, 1, 5],
    [3, 12, 8],
    [2, 5, 9]
])


test2 = Matrix([
    [5, 2, 1],
    [10, 2, 9],
    [0, 1, 3]
])

invmat = test.inverse()

mattest = pow(test, 10)

addtest = test + test2 + 5
subtest = test - test2
multtest = test * test2 * 2

sinmat = test(lambda x,y,v: math.sin(v))

test2[:2, :2] = 2
test[1:, :2] = test2[:2, 1:]
test[1, 1] = 10

reftest = Matrix([
    [1, 3, 5, 9],
    [1, 3, 1, 7],
    [4, 3, 9, 7],
    [5, 2, 0, 9]
])

ref = reftest.ref()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using numpy? Is this just for practice, or are you actually planning on using it?

Comment: @Dannnno just for practice really, I didn't make it with any plans for using it. I'm not usually very good at commenting either so I wanted to practice that too.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to create a class of exception called DimError, that all of your exceptions would inherit, this would make it so you could check all of them at the same time, which could be useful.

```
InvalidMatrixDimensions(DimError):
MismatchedMatrixDimensions(DimError)
UninvertibleMatrix(DimError):
```

Since you allow matrices to be called with `Matrix(raw_2d_list)`, I think you need width to get a default argument of None so that it doesn't complain that you didn't provide a width.

```
self.width = len(self._raw)
if self.width > 0:
```

Something is wrong here because len can never return -1.
My last comment would be that you should probably replace `__mul__` with `__matmul__` matmul was introduced in 3.5, and uses the @ operator specifically for matrix multiplication, and * for elementwise multiplication.